# "Switch label 'j' is the only reachable in the whole switch" What this statement means in JAVA?

Tags: java

Below is the code which i have added into IntelliJ IDEA [Community Version] using Java Language.[13v]
When I hover over j [beside case statement] I get following message - *Switch label 'j' is the only reachable in the whole switch* . What this statement means also program is running fine without any errors.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    
    int i = 10;
    final int j = 10;
    switch (i){
            case j:
                System.out.println("Hello");
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Nhi");
            default : break;
        }
        System.out.println(j);

    }
```

Comment: *FYI:* You should also have warnings that the two `case` blocks don't have a `break` statement.

Comment: Yeah , I am also aware about it .

Answer (score 3):

IntelliJ can tell from your code that `i == j`, and that `i != 2`. So IntelliJ is warning you that the `case 2` and the `default` don't make much sense, since (the way you have the function written right now) `i` cannot equal 2 and that the switch will not jump directly to the `default` case.

This isn't IntelliJ giving you an error message, its just a warning/diagnostic message. Your code will still run fine the way it is written right now.

Comment: Thanks for helping
After reading ur Answer i realized what that statement is  trying to say.
Sometimes we focus on code so much that we forget about the basic English comprehension .